# Planets won't render when using for-loop in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, iteration

I am running an N-body simulation (testing with three planets at first) and it appears when I use a for-loop to do so, all of the planets don't render and while debugging i found out they don't even have an address. However, if I manually type in the movement of all three planets it works. Here's my code:

```
    public MainScreen(final Application application) {
        this.application = application;
        planets = new ArrayList<>();

        cam = new OrthographicCamera(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        planet1 = new Planet(40, 1, 700, 450); // params consist of (r, m, x, y) in that order
        planet1.setVel(new Vector2(0, 400));
        planet2 = new Planet(80, 333000, 400, 450);
        planet3 = new Planet(20, 1, 200, 450);
        planet3.setVel(new Vector2(0, 400));

        planets.add(planet2);
        planets.add(planet1);
        planets.add(planet3);

    }    


public void render(float delta) {
        ScreenUtils.clear(0, 0, 0, 1);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);


        batch.begin();
        planet1.render(batch);
        planet2.render(batch);
        planet3.render(batch);
        cam.position.set(planet2.getPos().x + planet2.getR(), planet2.getPos().y + planet2.getR() - 30, 0);
        cam.update();
        batch.end();

        for(int i = 0; i < planets.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < planets.size(); j++) {
                planets.get(i).move(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), planets.get(j));
            }
        }
    }
```

It leaves them unrendered. However if I do the following it works:

```
planet1.move(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), planet2);
planet1.move(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), planet3);
planet2.move(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), planet1);
planet2.move(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), planet3);
//... etc
```

Comment: What is `planets`? I supposed its a list but where is it defined and how is it filled? And have you checked if maybe that list is empty when it reaches the loop and that's why nothing happens? Or maybe it doesn't contain the 3 objects you also reference as `planet1`, `planet2` and `planet3`.

Comment: i edited the question so it should be clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not doing any rendering in the loop, I'm guessing you're doing something to their positions that moves them out of view of the camera. Shouldn't you be checking `if (i != j)` in your loop? I'm assuming you don't want a planet to be affected by itself in the move function.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < planets.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < planets.size(); j++) {
            if (i == j) continue;
            planets.get(i).move(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), planets.get(j));
        }
    }
```

By the way, usually you update the simulation before rendering, or else your visuals are always lagging the physics by one frame.

Comment: "usually you update the simulation before rendering" so it would suffice to call `move()` before `render()` or is there something else meant by update?

Comment: That’s what I meant.